# No commutator or rectifier?

Tags: electromagnetism, electronics, electrical-engineering

Homopolar motors and generators don't need a commutator or rectifier. Are there any other motors or generators that don't need a commutator or rectifier? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any other motors or generators that don't need a commutator
>   or rectifier?

That old work horse, the ac induction motor. There may be others as well, but I'm not aware of them.

Hope this helps.